# implicit declaration of function 'objc_lookUpClass'

Tags: objective-c

I am getting this warning for the line code:

```
Class myClass = objc_lookUpClass([_className UTF8String]);
```

I am adding

```
#import <Foundation/NSObjCRuntime.h>
#import <objc/objc.h>
```

And it still don't resolve the problem

Another warning i get on this line is:
"Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Comment: The "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast" is probably because it can't find the function declaration for `objc_lookUpClass`, so it assumes that the function is declared `extern int objc_lookUpClass(...);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the doc, you'll see that [`objc_lookUpClass` returns an `id`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-objc_lookUpClass), not a `Class`. To suppress the warning you either need to make `myClass` an `id`, or cast the return value to a `Class`:

```
Class myClass = (Class)objc_lookUpClass([_className UTF8String]);
```

BTW, there is [NSClassFromString](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJDAJA) if you have an NSString.

```
Class myClass = NSClassFromString(_className);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import this header:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```